# Angular D3 understanding attrTween function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand how to use the function attrTween in D3. 
I'm trying to implement a pie-chart from the following example:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636 .

I'm having issues however when I arrive to the transition part.

```
  private populateGauge(): void {
    const innerRadius = this.radius - 50;
    const outerRadius = this.radius - 10;
    const arc = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .startAngle(0);

    const background = this.svg
      .append('path')
      .datum({ endAngle: this.tau })
      .style('fill', '#ddd')
      .attr('d', arc);
    this.myEndAngle = { endAngle: (this.gaugeData.value / 100) * this.tau };
    const foreground = this.svg
      .append('path')
      .datum(this.myEndAngle)
      .style('fill', 'orange')
      .attr('d', arc);

    foreground
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .attrTween('d', function(newAngle) {
        return function(d) {
          const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
          return function(t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return arc(d);
          };
        };
      });
    }
```

[image: error]

I've been trying to use easy base cases and just using 0's in the interpolate function but I cant get rid of a final error, which the last return statement is throwing (return arc(d));

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'DefaultArcObject'.

How do I get arround these problems?
Let me know if you need more information provided.

Comment: I assume this runs fine. You just want to silent the TypeScript warning? Getting the types right with D3 and TypeScript can be a pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attrTween('d',...)` takes a single function that returns another function. You pass it a function that gets called with the current *datum*, *index* and current *node* as the parameters. This function should return the interpolation function which gets called with a *time* value.

When I look at your source code. You have 3 nested functions, and that's not correct.

You need to have the *start* and *end* angles as values of the *datum*, and should not *mutate* the *datum* from inside a tween function.

I prefer to create an *arc* function outside the *tween* function, and then use that for my interpolation. Which is more effective since you're not creating a new *arc* function every time.

```
const myArc = d3.arc();
// ^^^ call methods of arc() to configure settings that won't animate.

foreground
  .transition()
  .duration(1500)
  .attrTween('d', (d) => {
      return (t) => {
        const angle = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.newAngle)(t);
        // ^^^ interpolate datum values using time.
        myArc.startAngle(angle);
        // ^^^ call methods of arc() to configure what you need.
        return myArc(null);
        // ^^^ call arc function to render "d" attribute.
      };
    };
  });
```

I find it easier to use the node package "@types/d3"

```
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

You can then import these types into the TypeScript file

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

If you have an IDE like WebStorm. You can CTRL+CLICK on a D3 function and see the type definitions and comments.

Comment: And in VS Code (which it looks like the OP is using) you can see the type definitions by clicking F12 - Go to definition

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It runs, but not with an animation effect I'm afraid.. 
I've been sitting with this function all day. This is how I modified it after your post:
https://i.gyazo.com/9dc8dd33013dcbc6df71be327d10c195.png

This isnt causing any actual runtime errors, but it isnt showing the transition either.